# Sefer similar to Yalkut Yosef for Ashkenazim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, ashkenazi

Yalkut Yosef is a revolutionary work for the Sefardic world. He covers every aspect of practical Halacha as understood by his father Hacham Ovadia (who mostly follows the Shulchan Aruch) and applies them to modern day situations. He is extremely comprehensive and generally brings down every relevant opinion in his footnotes. He does all this in a clear, understandable, and easy-to-read manner which targets a wide range, from the Talmid Hacham to your average layman.

**Is there a Sefer like this for Ashkenazim?** The Mishna Berura (Biur Halacha and Shaar HaSiyun) are more for Lamdanim to learn from. What's great about Yalkut Yosef is that everyone can learn from it.

I even was speaking to an Ashkenazi Yeshiva Bochur about this today.

Comment: @Vram 1) Hacham Ovadia doesn't discuss *every* Halacha. E.G. the first Halacha in Yalkut Yosef "Yitgaber KaAri". There is no Halacha in Sifre Hacham Ovadia "Yitgaber KaAri" so places where Halachot are obvious he quotes SA. 2) I'm pretty sure he did. At least in a some of the volumes.

Comment: @Vram his point wasn't to sum up his father's Halacha. His point was to make a book that could be used for everyday situations.

Comment: @Vram as I said before: he wasn't trying to write "Kitzur Piske Hacham Ovadia", rather a more modern version of the SA **based** on his father's way of learning and Pesakim

Comment: Does anyone know about the Sefer Pisek Teshuvos? It seems to be pretty similar.

Comment: @Vram it seems to do something similar...but it looks like he doesn't mention the first 350 Siman in Orah Haim.

Comment: Is the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch too old to fit?  It's concise, thorough, and very easy to learn.

Answer (score 10):

There is also [Peninei Halacha](http://ph.yhb.org.il/), from Rav Eliezer Melamed, which is not as comprehensive as Yalkut Yosef, but does go through all the main relevant halachos in Orach Chaim (and other areas of halacha too) and reaches a psak on each issue.

Answer (score 5):

[Piskei Tshuvos](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?main_page=product_reviews&products_id=364) is a 5 or 6 volume set which summarizes (**and gives Maarei Mkomos for**) Tshuvos (that have practical ramifications) which deal in Orach Chayim.

He goes Siman by Siman in the order of the Shulchan Aruch (and within the Shulchan Aruch, he goes in the order of the Mishna Brura).

Comment: Does he mention every single Pesak of the S"A and M"B?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill my question is for people who 15 minutes to learn Halacha everyday. By the time they do one SA and MB there is already no time for BH SH and PT. Yalkut Yosef takes Bet Yosef, SA, and Hacham Ovadia and gives you the most of your 15 minutes.

Comment: if you take the tamtzit of the Yalkut Yosef (aka kitzur) it is two volumes. Most of YY is sources.

Comment: Shmuel, did you mean to say that within **Orach Chayim** he goes according to the order of the Mishnah Berurah?

Comment: It was just a question of phrasing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very familiar with Yalkut Yosef but I believe, based on your description, that the [Aruch HaShulchan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aruch_HaShulchan) would be comparable for Ashkenazim.

Comment: my edition has 8 volumes, but it covers all 4 sections of the shulchan aruch (as opposed to the mishna brura)

Comment: I'm talking about something more modern that would discuss things that we have in our times (computers etc.).

Comment: then I do not believe a single work exists for ashkenazim. A comprehensive work that I know is very popular is Rabbi Ribiat's 39 Melachos, however that work is only on hilchos shabbos and is ~1,500 pages long (plus 1,000 pages of notes). I can't imagine how voluminous a work that covers all of shulchan aruch at that level would have to be!

Comment: @Moshe Yalkut Yosef I believe is 24 volumes. http://hanut.olam-jew.com/index.php?productID=174 they should be able to make the same for Ashkenazim.

Comment: I am speaking mainly out of ignorance here but I believe that sefardim have localized halachik authority into a select few poskim whereas ashkenazim have many different viewpoints that would need to be considered. For most sefardim if Rav Ovadia says its ok, that's good enough, for most ashkenazim there is not (and has not been, since possibly Rav Moshe Feinstein) one posek who carries as much weight for as many people.

Comment: @HachamGabriel thought this might be of interest to you http://torahmusings.com/2012/02/mishna-berura-vs-aruch-hashulchan/

Comment: Sefer Ashrei Ha'ish

Answer (score 3):

The [Nitei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/46446)  is an attempt at such a work (though he is *by no means* complete, or even going in order. I don't know if he will ever do such "simple" halachos like "laws of Davening" etc.).

Comment: His sefer is very minhag based

Answer (score 3):

There is an amazing set called Tzurbah M'Rabannan. It goes through the whole Shulchan Aruch(not every single siman though). It is very relvant halachaos but is taught from gemara down to modern day poskim. It also gives sefardic and ashakanazic halacha lmaaseh. Its really amazing,bought it recently.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where can I buy it in America? I can't find it anywhere online. @sam

Comment: It is not in America yet,I had it shipped via ship

Comment: And it's semi similar to Yalkut Yosef? @sam

Comment: I wouldn't completely compare it to it,but it is very easy to read. It is unique

Comment: Can you send me a picture of how it looks inside. Even though I see the one up top^ @sam

Comment: I will b"n add a pic of mine

Answer (score 1):

Shone Halachot of Harav Haim Kanievsky Shelti"a in conjunction with Piske Teshuvot should get the job done.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch?lang=bi). (Actually, since the Kitzur was published in 1884 by Rabbi Shlomo Ganzfried, wouldn't that make Yalkut Yosef the Sephardi equivalent to the Kitzur?)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote and why it wasn't the first one to be said

Comment: @Kazibácsi I at least don't see how this book is similar to Yalkut Yosef at all. They are about as different a Halakha book as one could imagine. Why do you think this should be an answer here? The question sought a work that "covers every aspect of practical Halacha... applies them to modern day situations... is extremely comprehensive and generally brings down every relevant opinion in his footnotes... does all this in a clear, understandable, and easy-to-read manner which targets a wide range, from the Talmid Hacham to your average layman."

Comment: That doesn't sound remotely like the Kitzur ShA which covers only common areas of Halakha, doesn't touch on modern applications, isn't comprehensive, doesn't note other opinions, doesn't even have footnotes, doesn't really target the higher range, though it is pretty clear to read perhaps mostly due to skipping on more nuanced positions and background.