# Hagahot to Kitzur Yalkut Yosef

Tags: halacha, ashkenazi, hacham-ovadia-yosef

[Related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14793/sefer-similar-to-yalkut-yosef-for-ashkenazim)

Has any Ashkenazi posek or commentator written glosses on the Yalkut Yosef with opinions according to Ashkenazi minhagim (where they differ of course)?

Comment: What would be the point of that? Sepharadim have Yalkut Yosef, Ashkenazim have Mishna Berura.

Comment: Yalkut Yosef represents a broader stream of thought than Mishnah Berurah.