# Should an Ashkenazi learn Yalkut Yosef and Kaf HaChaim?

Tags: jewish-books, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, hacham-ovadia-yosef

Should and Ashkenazi such as myself learn Yalkut Yosef and Kaf HaChaim, Sephardi halachic works, or should I not bother as the halacha wouldn't apply to me?

Comment: Do you only ever engage in Talmud Torah via directly relevant piskei halakha and nothing else?

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe spin that into some sort of answer...?

Comment: no im just wondering

Comment: If you don't only ever engage in Talmud Torah via directly relevant piskei halakha then why are you wondering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how it would hurt to learn them, as long as you aren't sacrificing learning time you could be using to learn more relevant halacha. Learning Sephardi halacha may not be useful to your own practice, but it may help you in understanding someone else's practice.

Consider this - do Ashkenazim always pasken the way the Shulchan Aruch brings halacha? How about the Mishneh Torah, or even the Gemara? Yet would we throw out learning these works simply because we don't pasken like them? Heaven forbid.

I'd hardly say there isn't any "point" to it. As I said before, I just wouldn't sacrifice learning time you could be using to learn more relevant halacha in order to study them.

For what it's worth, I, an Ashkenazi, have done a little reading myself in Yalkut Yosef. It's helped me out before in understanding Sephardi practice, and in answering a few Mi Yodeya questions. Conversely, I've known many Sephardim who've learnt the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch from Rabbi Shlomo Ganzfried, even though all the halacha is like Ashkenazim. (Of course, nowadays you can even find a Kitzur Shulchan Aruch with notes on Sephardi halacha.)

Comment: ok thanks so much this is a great answer ezra

Comment: @AviKupchik nisht do farvos

Comment: I would think there might be a difference between Rambam/Gemara on the one hand and Kaf Hachaim/Yalkut Yosef on the other hand. The former, even when not representative of the Ashkenazi final halacha, are still reckoned with in subsequent halachic literature, and are often the basis of subsequent halachic literature. The latter are not the basis of, nor reckoned with in Ashkenazic halacha (for the most part).

Comment: @AviKupchik if you consider it a great answer, perhaps upvote it and/or accept it... (I'm currently the only upvoter)

Comment: @Alex But the Yalkut Yosef and the Kaf haChaim will also bring down Ashkenazi sources

Comment: So no Ashkenzi should study anything but Ashkenazi conclusions/rulings until they've mastered all of them?

Comment: So no Ashkenzi should study anything but Ashkenazi conclusions/rulings until they've mastered all of them?

Comment: There've been a few times I've had to consult Kitzur Yalkut Yosef or the Ben Ish Chai when by Sephardi friends of mine. I've also led bentsching a few times, being a Kohen, which is strange when one considers that I was leading Sephardi Birkat hAmazon with Ashkenazis

Comment: @DoubleAA Did I say that? I said he should not sacrifice any learning time he could be using to learn more relevant halacha. I did not say anything about him mastering Ashkenazi halacha. That would take a lifetime. :)

Comment: Yes you said it. That's the same thing. Unless you mean to exclude the case where this is the only book available? When else would one not very sacrificing time they could spend learning Ashkenzi Halakhic conclusions?

Comment: @DoubleAA Suppose you either have time in your learning time to either learn the Mishnah Berurah or Yalkut Yosef. Obviously as an Ashkenazi I think it would be best to learn MB over YY. Not everyone can learn 24/7, some people only have certain hours in the day when they can learn. This is what I meant.

Comment: It still feels like you're completely agreeing with everything I said

Comment: @DoubleAA The difference is that you made the assumption that I meant to say that an Ashkenazi should not learn YY until he's mastered all of Ashkenazi halacha. That's not what I said at all.

Comment: It is very clearly exactly what you said. When else are you no longer sacrificing learning more relevant Halakhic conclusions? Must be when you learned it already

Comment: @Aaron That could be an answer to the question. But that's not what this answer said.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to learn "plain old Torah", or you are studying in order to Pasken for Sefardim, this would be a useful resource.

If you want to learn it for the purposes of Ashkenazi Pesak Halacha, consider some of the alternatives mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14793/16354).